# Как можно заменить определенный текст в PDF файле? Python

Tags: python, pdf

Допустим у меня есть PDF файл

> *имя: Иван
>
> Возвраст: 18*

Как мне изменить значение 18 на любое другое используя Python?
Спасибо большое за ответ!
P.s: PDF файл это не словарь, просто привел пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прямого пути для этого в Python нет, т.к. PDF -- это не HTML: нельзя так просто взять и сделать replace, в основе PDF лежит совершенно иной принцип (почитайте, как устроен этот формат, если вкратце: что-то типа массива символ-позиция-оформление вместо сплошного текста). Но есть костыль в виде:

https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor

Пример поиска и заменты текста:

```
#;encoding=utf-8
# Example file to redact Social Security Numbers from the
# text layer of a PDF and to demonstrate metadata filtering.

import re
from datetime import datetime

import pdf_redactor

## Set options.

options = pdf_redactor.RedactorOptions()

options.metadata_filters = {
    # Perform some field filtering --- turn the Title into uppercase.
    "Title": [lambda value : value.upper()],

    # Set some values, overriding any value present in the PDF.
    "Producer": [lambda value : "My Name"],
    "CreationDate": [lambda value : datetime.utcnow()],

    # Clear all other fields.
    "DEFAULT": [lambda value : None],
}

# Clear any XMP metadata, if present.
options.xmp_filters = [lambda xml : None]

# Redact things that look like social security numbers, replacing the
# text with X's.
options.content_filters = [
    # First convert all dash-like characters to dashes.
    (
        re.compile(u"[−–—~‐]"),
        lambda m : "-"
    ),

    # Then do an actual SSL regex.
    # See https://github.com/opendata/SSN-Redaction for why this regex is complicated.
    (
        re.compile(r"(?<!\d)(?!666|000|9\d{2})([OoIli0-9]{3})([\s-]?)(?!00)([OoIli0-9]{2})\2(?!0{4})([OoIli0-9]{4})(?!\d)"),
        lambda m : "XXX-XX-XXXX"
    ),

    # Content filter that runs on the text comment annotation body.
    (
        re.compile(r"comment!"),
        lambda m : "annotation?"
    ),
]

# Filter the link target URI.
options.link_filters = [
    lambda href, annotation : "https://www.google.com" 
]

# Perform the redaction using PDF on standard input and writing to standard output.
pdf_redactor.redactor(options)
```